# Could not load file or assembly System.Net.Http using mono

Tags: c#, mono

I am developing a discord bot in C# and to have it 24/7 I plan to host it in a pi zero with mono because the zero cannot run net core

I am using visual studio 2019 to make it targeting .NET Framework 4.6.2, after compiling I get a Release folder with the exe and a bunch of dll libraries then try to run the program in my pi using

```
mono 'discord bot net framework.exe'
```

in my windows 10 PC it works fine but when I try to run it on the pi I get the following error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type of
> field 'Discord.Net.Rest.DefaultRestClient:_client' (1) due to: Could
> not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
> dependencies.   at Discord.API.DiscordRestApiClient.SetBaseUrl
> (System.String baseUrl) [0x00011] in
> <790e6351624946dea6c24efa0b8ebeb3>:0   at
> Discord.API.DiscordRestApiClient..ctor
> (Discord.Net.Rest.RestClientProvider restClientProvider, System.String
> userAgent, Discord.RetryMode defaultRetryMode,
> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer, Discord.RateLimitPrecision
> rateLimitPrecision, System.Boolean useSystemClock) [0x0006a] in
> <790e6351624946dea6c24efa0b8ebeb3>:0   at
> Discord.API.DiscordSocketApiClient..ctor
> (Discord.Net.Rest.RestClientProvider restClientProvider,
> Discord.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketProvider webSocketProvider,
> System.String userAgent, System.String url, Discord.RetryMode
> defaultRetryMode, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer,
> Discord.RateLimitPrecision rateLimitPrecision, System.Boolean
> useSystemClock) [0x00021] in :0   at
> Discord.WebSocket.DiscordSocketClient.CreateApiClient
> (Discord.WebSocket.DiscordSocketConfig config) [0x00020] in
> :0   at
> Discord.WebSocket.DiscordSocketClient..ctor
> (Discord.WebSocket.DiscordSocketConfig config) [0x00000] in
> :0   at
> Not_traso.StartUp.ConfigureServices
> (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection services)
> [0x00015] in :0   at
> Not_traso.StartUp.RunAsync () [0x0001e] in
> :0   at Not_traso.StartUp.RunAsync
> (System.String[] args) [0x00065] in
> :0   at Not_traso.Program.Main
> (System.String[] args) [0x00060] in
> :0   at Not_traso.Program.
> (System.String[] args) [0x0000c] in
> :0 [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED
> EXCEPTION: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type of field
> 'Discord.Net.Rest.DefaultRestClient:_client' (1) due to: Could not
> load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
> dependencies.   at Discord.API.DiscordRestApiClient.SetBaseUrl
> (System.String baseUrl) [0x00011] in
> <790e6351624946dea6c24efa0b8ebeb3>:0   at
> Discord.API.DiscordRestApiClient..ctor
> (Discord.Net.Rest.RestClientProvider restClientProvider, System.String
> userAgent, Discord.RetryMode defaultRetryMode,
> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer, Discord.RateLimitPrecision
> rateLimitPrecision, System.Boolean useSystemClock) [0x0006a] in
> <790e6351624946dea6c24efa0b8ebeb3>:0   at
> Discord.API.DiscordSocketApiClient..ctor
> (Discord.Net.Rest.RestClientProvider restClientProvider,
> Discord.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketProvider webSocketProvider,
> System.String userAgent, System.String url, Discord.RetryMode
> defaultRetryMode, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer,
> Discord.RateLimitPrecision rateLimitPrecision, System.Boolean
> useSystemClock) [0x00021] in :0   at
> Discord.WebSocket.DiscordSocketClient.CreateApiClient
> (Discord.WebSocket.DiscordSocketConfig config) [0x00020] in
> :0   at
> Discord.WebSocket.DiscordSocketClient..ctor
> (Discord.WebSocket.DiscordSocketConfig config) [0x00000] in
> :0   at
> Not_traso.StartUp.ConfigureServices
> (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection services)
> [0x00015] in :0   at
> Not_traso.StartUp.RunAsync () [0x0001e] in
> :0   at Not_traso.StartUp.RunAsync
> (System.String[] args) [0x00065] in
> :0   at Not_traso.Program.Main
> (System.String[] args) [0x00060] in
> :0   at Not_traso.Program.
> (System.String[] args) [0x0000c] in
> :0

I installed mono with sudo apt install mono-complete and updated to the latest version,

running mono --version gives

Mono JIT compiler version 6.12.0.122 (tarball Mon Feb 22 17:44:05 UTC 2021)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. [www.mono-project.com](http://www.mono-project.com)
TLS:           __thread
SIGSEGV:       normal
Notifications: epoll
Architecture:  armel,vfp+hard
Disabled:      none
Misc:          softdebug
Interpreter:   yes
LLVM:          yes(610)
Suspend:       preemptive
GC:            sgen (concurrent by default)

I have tried to install System.Net.Http with NuGet latest version and some previous versions but it doesn't work

I haven't used a pi or Linux before so I don't know where to even look for missing libraries or what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out discord net doesn't support mono anyways so there is nothing I can do, oh well.